# How can I compare a string to a "filter" list in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a collection of strings by a "filter" list... a list of bad words. The string contains a word from the list I dont want it.

I've gotten so far, the bad Word here is "frakk":

```
string[] filter = { "bad", "words", "frakk" };

string[] foo = 
{ 
    "this is a lol string that is allowed", 
    "this is another lol frakk string that is not allowed!"
};

var items = from item in foo 
            where (item.IndexOf( (from f in filter select f).ToString() ) == 0)
            select item;
```

But this aint working, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Any` + `Contains`:

```
var items = foo.Where(s => !filter.Any(w => s.Contains(w)));
```

if you want to compare case-insensitively:

```
var items = foo.Where(s => !filter.Any(w => s.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

**Update**: If you want to exlude sentences where at least one **word** is in the filter-list you can use `String.Split()` and `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
var items = foo.Where(sentence => !sentence.Split().Intersect(filter).Any());
```

[`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) is very efficient since it uses a `Set` under the hood. it's more efficient to put the long sequence first. Due to Linq's deferred execution is stops on the first matching word.

( note that the "empty" `Split` includes other white-space characters like tab or newline )

Comment: Won't this solution catch partial words?  It for instance would flag 'badmitten' as a bad word

Comment: @JaredPar: Edited my answer to include the word approach.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem you need to solve is breaking up the sentence into a series of words.  The simplest way to do this is based on spaces

```
string[] words = sentence.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

From there you can use a simple LINQ expression to find the profanities

```
var badWords = words.Where(x => filter.Contains(x));
```

However this is a bit of a primitive solution.  It won't handle a number of complex cases that you likely need to think about

- There are many characters which qualify as a space.  My solution only uses `' '`
- The split doesn't handle punctuations.  So `dog!` won't be viewed as `dog`.  Probably much better to break up words on legal characters

Comment: Would concatenating the list of bad words and putting that in as a regex match make more sense here than trying to worry about all of the various permutations of word splits?

Comment: @JimWooley that might be a better way to approach the problem. Esp given that `Regex` already has built-in mechanisms for word boundary detection (`\b`). I would still want to know more about the scenario before I recommended a regex though, I reserve them for non-critical scenarios (great for quick javascript validation but bad for anything on the server)

Comment: Why are server side regexs bad? (Genuine question)

Comment: @MarkWalsh they are just too easy to screw up even for people who frequently use them.  There are just too many cases to go through, hard to prove you got everything right.  For instance, most regexes don't take into account unicode strings and are easily broken by them

Comment: Ahh okay I see your point, especially RE: encoding.  Had a few nasty results with them on both sides of the fence, pity that so often they're unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your initial attempt didn't work is that this line:

```
(from f in filter select f).ToString()
```

evaluates to a string of the Array Iterator type name that's implied by the linq expression portion.  So you're actually comparing the characters of the following string:

``` System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator``2[System.String,System.String] ```

rather than the words of the filter when examining your phrases.